# OneSignal Subscribed Users?

Tags: cordova, onesignal

I have recently started to use OneSignal for push notifications for my Cordova project. I was able to make the push notifications when I am locally deploying my code. I wanted to know if OneSignal subscribes users when my app is on Google Play store? Is it automatically done that a user is added when a download is made or we have to handle this case?

Comment: a user is added when you do the initial handshake, ie the `init` function. Does have nothing to do with if an app is a debug version or a release version

Comment: Oh. Okay. Thanks a lot.

Comment: How did you end up doing this?

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is done automatically, no deference between local test and production test.

To make sure everything is working properly go to :

```
https://app.onesignal.com/apps/`[YOUR ONESIGNAL APP ID]`/players
```

Or chose `Audience` from the menu above then chose `All Users`. Now you can check subscribed users in real time (there is couple of minute delay)

[image: OneSignal All Users]